# When playing an Android video, how do you get callbacks when the user changes the position?

Tags: android, android-videoview, mediacontroller

If you have a VideoView hooked up to a MediaController, how do you get callbacks to know when the user uses the SeekBar?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you don't "know when the user uses the" `MediaController`. You can write your own controller, with your own `SeekBar`, to manage the user experience.